# ".innerHTML" Not Displaying Correctly On Safari (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, safari

#### My Problem:

Hey Everyone,

I'm currently trying to write some simple code that takes specific strings and makes them bold using only JavaScript. The code works fine, but when testing it on mobile I noticed that it doesn't display the newly boldened string correctly.

Instead, it doesn't display anything.

Can anyone help me out with this?

#### What I've Tried:

I thought that maybe since I was replacing the text using ".innerHTML" rather than ".innerText" it was causing some sort of issue, however, I need to use ".innerHTML" since the string that JavaScript is returning is in HTML formatting (ex. `<b>{Insert string here}</b>`).

I tried setting the inner text of the elements equal to their inner HTML, but that resulted in each string being displayed as "`<b>{Insert string here}</b>`" rather than just the bold text alone.

#### My Code:

```js
var text = document.getElementsByClassName('text-bold')
var boldText = []

for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++) { // For all of the elements with the class "text":
  var str = text[i].innerText // Get the inner text
  var bold = str.bold() // Make the inner text bold
  boldText.push(bold) // Return the string to an array
}

for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++) { // For all of the elements with the class "text":
  text[i].innerHTML = boldText[i] // Replace the inner HTML with the corresponding bold text from the array
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="text-bold">Hello!</p>
  <p class="text">Hi!</p>
  <p class="text-bold">Hey!</p>
</div>
```

#### UPDATE:

I initially thought this was an issue with mobile, but it seems as if it's only an issue with Safari.

Comment: Looks ok.  What mobile device/browser is having trouble?  [String.bold](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/bold) is deprecated, you could try `var bold = "<b>" + str + "</b>"` but I don't think it should matter.

Comment: Seems odd you just do not have a css class that makes it bold.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('.text-bold').forEach(function (elem) {
      elem.innerHTML = '<b>' + elem.textContent + '</b>';
    });`

Comment: @James It seems as if Safari is what's causing the issue, although I'm still unsure as to why. I didn't realize bold() was deprecated either, but I made your suggested change and am still getting the same issue.

Comment: Maybe your font does not support bold

Comment: Well, your code snippet above does produce bold font on my iphone/safari, I guess your particular problem is not related to this code.

Comment: If you accidentally gave an ancestor element the "text-bold" class - it would very much destroy the HTML of any child nodes.